# Maximum likelihood for $\lambda$ and $\delta$

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

> Consider $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ a random sample of an statistic population that is modeled by the density function:$$f(x)= \frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-(X-\delta)/\lambda} I_{[\delta,\infty)}$$
>
> Obtain maximum likelihood estimators for  $\delta $ and $\lambda$

We know 
 $$L(\delta,\lambda;X)=\prod_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-(X-\delta)/\lambda}=\frac{1}{\lambda^n}e^{-\frac{1}{\lambda}(\sum_{i=1}^NX_i-n\delta)}$$

Taking the log likelihood funtion we get

$$l(\delta,\lambda;X)=-n\ln (\lambda)-\frac{1}{\lambda}\sum_{i=1}^N (X_i-n\delta)$$

Taking the derivative with respect to the each parameter

$$\frac{\partial l}{\partial \delta}=\frac{n}{\lambda}$$

and

$$\frac{\partial l}{\partial \lambda}=-\frac{n}{\lambda}+(\sum_{i=1}^N X_i-n\delta)(\frac{1}{\lambda^2})$$

My problem comes when I want to maximize the functions. For $\hat\delta$, I think I need to involve minimum values; for $\frac{\partial l}{\partial \delta}=0$, I am not sure what to do. How can I proceed?

Comment: The smallest _possible_ value is $\delta,$ so you are right to focus on the minimum _observed_ value, often denoted $X_{(1)}.$ One doesn't always find the maximum of the likelihood function using calculus.

Comment: See [MLE for two-parameter exponential distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298874/mle-for-2-parameter-exponential-distribution/).